# Merge tags [spring-data-mongodb] and [spring-mongodb]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

It looks like [spring-data-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data-mongodb) (816 questions) already existed prior to the creation of [spring-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mongodb) (34 questions) and covers exactly the same topic. Could someone with the necessary rep please merge the tags or create a synonym?

Comment: there is also spring-mongo tag , that should be merged too. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/752176/spring-data-mongodb-duplicated-tags

Comment: @macias Once I get to 2500 rep, I'll make the synonym myself. Oh, I see that you're just over 2500! Could you make the tag synonyms?

Comment: I need to have have 5 total answer score on a tag to be able too :(

Comment: Oh. I didn't know about that requirement. :(

Comment: @oliver-gierke Not sure if you'll see this, but would you mind creating tag synonyms for these?

Comment: You now have the reputation to suggests the synonyms yourself.

Comment: @Adriaan Unfortunately, I'm in the same boat as macias. I don't have "a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag", so I can't yet suggest the synonyms.

Comment: Since the [tag:spring-mongo] tag has still not been merged over three years later, and it's technically a separate issue, I've created a post specifically for it.  Hopefully this will give it the visibility needed to actually occur.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408121/merge-tags-spring-mongo-and-spring-data-mongodb

Comment: Oh dear, this is annoying. I could create the synonym request reputation wise on [spring-data-mongodb]. But since there is a reverse synonym request and a synonym request between [spring-mongo] and [spring-mongodb] a new request can't be created for neither of them. :-(