# Merge tags [spring-mongo] and [spring-data-mongodb]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

[spring-mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mongo) should be made a synonym of [spring-data-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data-mongodb).

This was mentioned as [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314448/merge-tags-spring-data-mongodb-and-spring-mongodb#comment528844_314448) five years ago in an earlier synonym request for [spring-data-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data-mongodb) and [spring-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mongodb) ([Merge tags [spring-data-mongodb] and [spring-mongodb]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314448/merge-tags-spring-data-mongodb-and-spring-mongo)), but has not yet occurred.

Comment: Just for my understanding: `[spring-mongo]` and `[spring-mongodb]` should be synonyms of `[spring-data-mongodb]`?

Comment: There exists also a [spring-data-mongodb-reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-data-mongodb-reactive) tag, but I assume that this could be left as is

Comment: @Lino Yes that should be left separate, dealing withMongoDB reactive streams is different and less common than performing "normal" synchronous operations.